# Sorting lines in the file depends on the content of the file itself in c#

Tags: c#, sorting

The line content in my file is formatted as below:

```
Ref.,ID,Firstname,Secondname,City
```

Here is my file:

```
1,4234,Firstname1,Secondname1,City1
2,5647,Firstname2,Secondname2,City2
3,1657,Firstname3,Secondname3,City3
4,3898,Firstname4,Secondname4,City4
```

Now I want to sort it by the ID and put it again in the file like this:

```
3,1657,Firstname3,Secondname3,City3
4,3898,Firstname4,Secondname4,City4
1,4234,Firstname1,Secondname1,City1
2,5647,Firstname2,Secondname2,City2
```

Note: the whole line is a string variable.

So is there any way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
int counter = 0;
string ln; //Each line in file per loop   Ex:1,8957,Firstname,lastname,city

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Records in the file" + Environment.NewLine);

    Console.WriteLine("Ref,First name,Second name,City" + Environment.NewLine);

    while ((ln = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ln + Environment.NewLine);

        /*
        So here i need to sort the lines in the file, which written hard coded in the file before spliting it.
        */

        //split the current line (comma separated) into array of strings with Ref,Id,first name, last name and city respectively
        listLineElements = ln.Split(',').ToList();

        //get city (4th elemnt in the array)
        Student student = new Student(listLineElements[0], listLineElements[1], listLineElements[2], listLineElements[3], listLineElements[4]);

        //for each line call addIndex to check whether index is new? or add it to the secondary index list?
        addIndex(student.getCity(), ln);

        counter++; //counter for the number of read lines
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Madgy, welcome to stackoverflow. Nice question, but what you tried so far? Can you show us your attempt? Where did you stuck? Any error? Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also give us [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I suggest using the library CSV Helper (https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) to parse the raw file into structured data. This will make sorting easier without doing string manipulation yourself. Then you can use the library to write the sorted content back to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to store each line as a more organized custom Info object, then using [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1) to sort them. The class could be set up like...

```
class Info{
  public int Ref { get; set; };
  public int ID { get; set; };
  public string FirstName { get; set; };
  public string SecondName { get; set; };
  public string City { get; set; };

  Info(int ref, int id, string first, string second, string city)
  {
    Ref = ref; ID = id; FirstName = first; SecondName = second; City = city;
  }
}
```

Then, for each line, you could create one of these Info objects by...

```
string[] items = line.split(',');
Info lineInfo = new Info(Int32.Parse(items[0]),Int32.Parse(items [1]),items [2],items[3],items[4]);
```

Once you have an array / list of those Info objects, you can sort them using OrderBy

```
IEnumerable<Info> query = infoList.OrderBy(info => info.ID);
```

If your intention is to rewrite the sorted group of info from lines back to a file, you can just iterate back through that array / list and concatenate each field into a string.

```
foreach(Info info in query)
{
    file.WriteLine(info.Ref + "," + info.ID + "," + info.FirstName + "," + info.SecondName + "," + info.City);
}
```

Comment: I followed this steps, and finally it works , thank you so much for your help. ,, But there was a little issue in for each loop as it suppose to be (Info info in query) not (  (Info info in infoList) , i hope you edit it to be seen by the others, and here is after the modification i made in my code  `IEnumerable<Student> query = listLineElements3.OrderBy(s => s.id);`  `using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filePath)     {
          foreach (Student s in query)
                { file.WriteLine(s.R + "," + s.id + "," + s.firstName + "," + s.lastName + "," + s.city); }
            }`

Comment: Ah, yes thank you for pointing that out, silly mistake! Edited now!

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

string[] sortedLines = lines
    .Select(s => new
    {
        Line = s,
        SortKey = int.Parse(s.Split(',')[1])
    })
    .OrderBy(sl => sl.SortKey)
    .Select(sl => sl.Line)
    .ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(filePath, sortedLines);
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g8M8nQ